# Warping Image in Python with PIL

Tags: python, image-processing, operating-system, python-imaging-library

I have an image that I want to warp/scale to fit the black area of the image below. Is it possible to do this in python using the PIL framework? I'm currently a beginner in python and have no idea how I would go about doing this. Could someone please explain how to do this. the dimensions are 2794x 2463 for both images I just don't know how to warp it to fit the black area on the image below using the PIL framework in Python.

[image]

Could someone please explain how I would go about doing this?